# Re-call matplotlib graphs after inital call

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI which creates a budget calculator and stores transactions. One of the buttons on the GUI is a call to a script that creates charts from the transaction data.

The first time I click the button, the graphs open up fine. If I attempt to click the button again, a blank figure comes up. I believe this comes from my initial,

```
plt.show()
```

call where I draw the graphs. Has anyone ran into a problem like this before?

GUI code:

```
ViewCharts = Button(win,text = 'View Spending Charts')
ViewCharts.grid(row = 21,column = 1)

def view_charts():
    Graphs.plot_charts()

ViewCharts.configure(command = view_charts)
```

Charts code:

```
global fig
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
global ax1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
global ax2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)


def plot_charts():
    category_bar_chart()
    category_pie_chart()
    fig = plt.show()
```

Where category_bar_chart() and category_pie_chart() are just functions to add plots into ax1 and ax2.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! I am working on Python3 on a Mac/PC depending on the time of day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are redefining `fig` when you do `fig = plt.show()` so after the first call, you no longer have the plots stored anywhere. Simply do `plt.show()` instead.

Comment: It's a little unclear how this code works exactly. Is the first segment immediately followed by the second?

Comment: To be honest, I had a feeling it would be confusing but was hoping someone recognized the issue. The two segments are in two seperate scripts, with the matplotlib plots coming from a script, Graphs.py. The whole thing is several hundred lines of code and I was unsure how to take snippets from the whole things.

Comment: The idea when having a problem like this is to produce a [mcve]. That is, you create a code which is some 20 lines long that shows the same kind of behaviour and thus reproduces the issue. However, the problem you have here seems to be that it is impossible to show a figure more than once using `plt.show()`; after it has been shown, it is gone so to speak. A possible solution is to recreate the figure on every buttom click.